# Correct way of passing a PHP $variable to MySQLI

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, variables, mysqli

I am wondering about the safe or correct way to pass a $variable to a query. I am new to PHP thats why I am asking such beginner question. Here is the example one and two, which one is correct and safer because of symbols?

Example one:

```
//here is the line I am asking about. The $identification
$query = "SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `username` = '$identification' LIMIT 1";
```

Example two:

```
//here is the line I am asking about. The $identification
$query = "SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `username` = '" . $identification . "' LIMIT 1";
```

I don't need answers about PHP 4 or 5 or PDO. I just need to know what is correct:

This

```
'" . $identification . "'
```

Or this

```
'$identification'
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: Cannot run php 5 on my shared hosting provider

Comment: I can't believe, what is your php version? and who is your hosting provider?

Comment: *"Cannot run php 5 on my shared hosting provider"* - You have `mysqli_` code in your question. Guess what; `mysqli_` runs on PHP 5. http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php

Comment: Hello Fred. Really? My hosting provider said they run 4.5 or 4 point something. I tried to run a script and it did not worked

Comment: could you provide the hosting conpany link please? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL version 5 was released 10 years ago. that means for IT like minimum 2 or 3  generation of hardware/software plarforms past away. where did you find such hoster?

Comment: It's www.creattiva.cl

Comment: LOL ok I will call them to be sure

Comment: I edited the question because what I am asking about is something nobody is talking about

Comment: https://www.creattiva.cl/hosting-reseller/#fragment-3  *MySQL v4.1.21-standard / Enhanced
PHP v4.4.3*  run away!!!  imho you will meet hundreds issues if they never update software for 10 years

Comment: Yeah thats correct. Their servers are reall fast anyway and not cheap prices. Quality servers but using old php and they don't want to change

Comment: Jeez thats pricy, not sure whether your happy to outsource to another country but i know of at least one thats about the same price as their cheapest plan doing way more and more unlimited.

Comment: give me the url I will check it because I really want PHP 5 but in the American continent

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
 $query = 
 "SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `username` = '" . 
 mysql_escape_string($identification) . 
 "' LIMIT 1";
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php

However, `mysql_escape_string` is deprecated. If you can, you should use `mysql_real_escape_string`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: Php has deprecated that:

"This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. "

Comment: @Krycke, I know, but the OP has stated he cannot use > PHP 5

Comment: Alright, but if he can use a PHP version >= 4.3 then mysql_real_escape_string should be used at least.

Comment: I edited the question because what I am asking about is something nobody is talking about

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use PDO instead of the mysqli extension (works with php 5.1 and above)

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059

Comment: I edited the question because what I am asking about is something nobody is talking about